# I arrived in NYC on August 18, 2017 or I arrived on August 18, 2017 in nyc

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, time-reference

> I arrived in NYC on August 18, 2017

or

> I arrived on August 18, 2017 in NYC

in English language one puts date of arrival before place of arrival, or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Both would be considered grammatical, but I would use either

> I arrived in NYC on August 18, 2017

or

> On August 18, 2017, I arrived in NYC.

See also: [englisch-hilfen.de:](https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/satzstellung_2.htm)

> Expressions of time go at the end of a statement.
>
> - At the end of the sentence: Place before Time
> - NEVER put Place or Time between Verb and Object - <s>*I have in the kitchen breakfast*</s>.
> - Definite expressions of time can also go at the beginning of the sentence if they are not the main focus in the sentence. If you are in doubt – put it at the end of the sentence – it is more likely to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct. My personal preference for usage is the first form if I am emphasizing the fact of arrival in the stated location; if I am emphasizing the fact that the arrival was on the specific date, I will use the second form.